# Fluke or Naming Error

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Under the directory of my `C:\Users\ME` I have a directory called `C:\Users\ME\Invoices`. Its where I keep my bookkeeping and all that. However, I created a `*.bat` file, I called it `Invoices.bat`. I bet everyone knows where this is going, in the file I had the following script:

```
start C:\Users\ME\Invoices
```

For some reason, Windows CMD was going in a loop and kept spawning CMD's Prompts. Thankfully my computer didn't crash I closed the windows. However, the issue made me curious of course I have in my `PATH=C:\Users\ME`. Was the system confused about what to start? Or was it the fact they had the same name, by chance I changed the `*.bat` file name to `Bookkeeping.bat` and it executed just fine? I would like to know your thoughts about the issue is that a fluke, or the same name error. I would like to make noted that I tried it with both explorer.exe running and not running.

Comment: You probably need to name the program in your batch file that you are trying to "start"   I don't think you can "start" a folder.

Comment: @John: You can, the `start` command in Cmd ends up calling ShellExecute() to get the same default action for that filetype as Explorer or the Run dialog would. (This includes opening URLs and so on.)

Comment: Thank you. I normally name things explicitly to ensure they work correctly all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `start`

> When executing a command line whose first token does NOT contain an
> extension, then CMD.EXE uses the value of the PATHEXT
> environment variable to determine which extensions to look for
> and in what order.  The default value for the PATHEXT variable
> is:

```
    .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD

Notice the syntax is the same as the PATH variable, with
semicolons separating the different elements.
```

And also

> When searching for an executable, if there is no match on any extension,
> then looks to see if the name matches a directory name.  If it does, the
> START command launches the Explorer on that path.  If done from the
> command line, it is the equivalent to doing a CD /D to that path.

So yeah, it's because your file name matches the folder name.